# Like and Unlike post using wordpress rest api jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to add a system where a normal user(no need to sign in) can vote in a faq post.
when he/she clicked on yes or no then it will be counted and show in my backend.
How can i do this??
[image: This is user section[![this is background section]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWJyn.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want frontend user to vote, you should :

- Edit the template of your frontend post (or listing page) to add the required HTML (buttons)
- Create a custom POST API route
- Create the JS to POST to the API route, with a particular parameter for the upvote, another for the downvote, and the post ID
- Create 2 ACF fields (integer) to be increased, on your post
- use the plugin Admin Columns to add those count columns to your backend table
- in the PHP method handling your new API route, increase upvote meta or downvote meta depending POST data.
- The same method should check for:

  - Whether the user already voted this post from Session data and depending on your logic increase/decrease one of the post meta
  - Check that the voted post is public, and can be rightfully voted
  - save an array in user session to prevent multi-vote, and highlight up/downvote buttons if he already voted
- Edit your frontend template to highlight one or the other button, and prevent upvote on click using JS if already upvoted, only allow downvote or nothing etc... depending the logic you want